# Did Krishna became old while dying?

Tags: krishna, death, body

Was Krishna young when he was dying ? Or Was he old ? I mean not necessarily by his age but by his appearance. Was Krishna Ajara ?

Answer (score 1):

Lord Krishna was very old when he died. I don't know what he looked like when he died.

There is a Chandogya Upanishad mantra which says:

> Ghora Angirasa expounded this well known doctrine to Devaki's son
> Krishna and said , 'Such a knower should at the time of death repeat
> this triad - "Thou art the imperishable, Thou art the unchangeable,
> Thou art the subtle essence of Prana." (on hearing the above) Krishna
> became thirstless. There are two Rk stanzas in regard to this.

**Chandogya Upanishad mantra 3.17.6**

Swami Swahananda writes:

> Sri Sankaracharya states that the mention of Krishna is only for the
> purpose of bringing out the excellence of this Vidya (sacrifice). He
> says that the desire for Vidyas was quenched in the mind of Krishna
> after listening to the instruction of Gora Angirasa. The Mimamsakas
> whose central dogma is that every syllable of the Sruti is
> beginningless and eternal would consider the reference to Krishna as
> Arthavada and not an allusion to the historical personality. Students
> of historical thought, however, find a definite reference to the
> teacher of the Gita in the epithet Devakiputra. This conclusion is
> rendered probable by the identification of man and sacrifice
> (corresponding to the Gita ideal of the dedication of every activity
> of life to the Divine) and **by the long life of Sri Krishna extending
> to 128 years described in the Bhagavata** while a period of 116 years is
> considered normal in this Vidya. In this passage historians find the
> earliest reference to Sri Krishna which can not be dismissed as
> legendary.

**Chandogya Upanishad commentary by Swami Swahananda**